# Reading words from a file and encrypting each of them line by line in C

Tags: c, encryption, sha512

I am fairly new to the C programming language. I would like to seek guidance in encrypting words from a text file and displaying it. Here's what I have done so far. I would like to apologise in advance for the formatting as I'm rather new to stack-overflow.

File-reader1.c is a program I intend to use to read from the text file.

## File-reader1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *ptr_file;  //declaring a file
    char buf[1000];
    char * hash_type_1 = "$1$";  // md5 hash
    char * hash_type_2 = "$6$";  // sha512 hash
    char * salt_1 ="$";     //a simple salt
    char * result;
    char encyption_scheme[20];
    
    ptr_file = fopen("small_wordlist","r"); //opening the file
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file) != NULL)
        printf("%s",buf);

    // prepare the first call using md5

    strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_1);
    strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
    result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
    printf("MD5 Result\n");
    printf("%s\n",result);
    
    // prepare the second call using sha-512 
    strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_2);
    strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
    result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
    printf("SHA-512\n");
    printf("%s\n",result);
    
    fclose(ptr_file); //closing the file
    return 0;
}
```

Small_Wordlist is a file containing a list of words I would like to encrypt.

## Small_wordlist

```
Andy 

Noel

Liam

Paul
```

My output is as follows :

```
Noel

Liam

Andy

Paul

MD5 Result

$1$$.NeC/EbTUibao2by.HNV01

SHA-512

$6$$qQs5aHFZX/2Iaz4Y1RIihRn./AszpUZnDfld0h5mrWEtAqRJPanIO3cpT3TOOKuFS5hpmLrKAb5MY2mGV2ato1
```

As you can see. Only one instance of hashing has been done for both SHA 512 and MD5. However, I would like all four words to be hashed with both schemes. Would you be so kind as to walk me through the steps I need to do to accomplish it ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: from the code, it looks as if that's exactly what you are doing already.  What makes you think it is not?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The reason why I believe I have yet to achieve  the intent of the program is because I have only managed to produce 1 SHA-512 and 1 MD5 hash for just 1 word out of the list. On the other hand what I need to do is produce 4 MD5 hashes and 4 SHA-512 hashes for each of the words in the wordlist.

Comment: You will most likely want to remove the trailing `'\n'` from `buf`, otherwise you are including it in your encryption.

Comment: Hashing != Encryption

Comment: sha512 is too long to fit in `char encyption_scheme[20]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chuckling...

What happens if you add a `{` after

```
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
```

and a `}` before

```
fclose(ptr_file);//closing the file
```

You are simply reading and outputting `buf` and only encrypting the final word in the word-list `:)`

If it is unclear, you look like you intended to do the following:

```
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s",buf);

    /* prepare the first call using md5 */
    strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_1);
    strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
    result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
    printf("MD5 Result\n");
    printf("%s\n",result);

    /* prepare the second call using sha-512 */ 
    strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_2);
    strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
    result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
    printf("SHA-512\n");
    printf("%s\n",result);
}
```

To avoid including the trailing `'\n'` (read and included by `fgets`) in your encryption, I would recommend removing it before calling `crypt` using something similar to the following:

```
#define MAXC 1000
...
    while (fgets(buf,MAXC, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* get length */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check last char '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite with nul-char */
        else if (len == MAXC - 1) {         /* handle line too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line too long.\n");
            /* handle error as desired */
        }
        printf ("%s\n",buf);

        /* prepare the first call using md5 */
        strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_1);
        strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
        result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
        printf("MD5 Result\n");
        printf("%s\n",result);

        /* prepare the second call using sha-512 */ 
        strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_type_2);
        strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
        result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
        printf("SHA-512\n");
        printf("%s\n",result);
    }
```

(**note:** don't use *magic numbers* in your code, e.g. `1000` scattered throughout, instead, if you need a constant, `#define` one (or more))

look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Your post was helpful. I managed to get it done. Thank you :)

Comment: @catmix, then you should mark David's post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your file, you've read small_wordlist into `buf`. Then you call `crypt`, passing `buf` as the data. This is why the encryption only happens once: `buf` is being treated as one big string, and all the words are being encrypted together.

In order to change this behavior, you'll need to break `buf` apart into its composite words. A simple way to do this is to read through the buffer, replacing all whitespace characters with null terminators and saving the index of the start of each word. Then call `crypt` once for each word encountered, passing `buf + i` where `i` is the index of the beginning of the word.

There are, of course, other ways to break `buf` apart, but the important thing is that you'll need multiple calls to `crypt` to perform multiple encryptions.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just read one line from the file at a time.